# How to disable specific message displayed by contrib/core?

Tags: 7

I am using the [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module to disable one of the message which is being displayed to the end user. The message is:

> Anonymous (not verified) has requested to be your Friend. View your
>   pending friend requests to approve or decline.

To achieve this I have configured the module and written a regular expression to match a word from the message, But it seems to not be working.

Here is the code:

```
str.matches("(?i)(^|\\s+)(Anonymous (not verified))(\\s+|[.?!]$)");
```

Comment: It seems to be Off topic. This question is particularly related to forming rregular expression. It can be better answered in stackoverflow.

Comment: This involves using the use of a regex in a specific Drupal module.  I say this is on-topic here.

Comment: yes @MDP, I had tried using the whole message to be hidden but too its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Once a user has been deleted, The User relationships module have to delete all relationships associated to deleted user but it doesn't work correctly. I implemented `hook_user_delete()` in a custom module and delete non-approved relationships associated to the deleted user. like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_delete().
 */

function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_user_delete($account) {
  //user_relationships_delete_relationship($relationship, $user);
  db_delete('user_relationships')->condition('approved', 0 , '=')->condition(db_or()->condition('requester_id', $account->uid)->condition('requestee_id', $account->uid))->execute();
}
```